# webpage- weird spacing in firefox, renders correctly in chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm a relatively new web developer and I'm working on a online page.

The problem I am having is that there is a white spacing on Firefox just after the div `topcontainer` (the one with yellow background). On chrome it renders as intended.

Can someone please point me in the right direction or tell me what could be causing this?
Any additional help/tips on developing across browsers would also be appreciated.

```css
.topcontainer {
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.column {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
}
.orbit-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="topcontainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">Foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="orbit-container">Bar</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS and HTML?

Comment: there can't be a bug in Firefox, you must be doing something wrong, which make it work in Chrome by pure chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```css
.topcontainer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.topcontainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.column {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
}
.orbit-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="topcontainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">Foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="orbit-container">Bar</div>
```

Comment: @Jarg7 Works for me on Firefox 36

Answer (score 0):

Remove height from `.topcontainer`

ie, it should look like

```
.topcontainer {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: but i need the height because i wanted the .topcontainer shrunk.

Comment: Yes but it alters another aspect of the page.